# Google Compute instance is not receiving traffic from site to site vpn

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-vpn

I am trying to establish site to site vpn from Google cloud to my home. I am using Route based VPN option in Google cloud and I see that the connection is established from my home to Google cloud. When I ping my home network from Google compute instance, I can see the incoming traffic at home. But, Google compute instance is not receiving any traffic. I have the following routes

- Default route destination 0.0.0.0/0 next hop Internet gateway (automatically created)
- Default route destination 192.168.2.0/24 next hop vpc-network (automatically created)
- Route destination 192.168.1.0/24 next hop vpn-tunnel (I created to route traffic from GCP to my home)

The firewall is open from any ip to vpc network.

I am thinking it is a Routing/Firewall problem, but lost on the next steps to debug. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As this is a system administration question related, I would recommend to move it to Server Fault. You will find better help there.

Comment: Thanks Katie. I will move it over.